# Unknown error when trying to upgrade license

Tags: error-message, license

I just pushed a site live, and now when I log in to the control panel and get the message to upgrade my license, when I click "upgrade your license", I get a blank modal and a message that "An Unknown Error Occurred".

Everything has been running fine up to this point on the same server, using its ip address, rather than the url.

I'm getting the following errors in my log file:

```
015/09/21 22:30:32 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.403] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in .../craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php:442
Stack trace:
#0 .../craft/app/controllers/AppController.php(118): Craft\UserSessionService->requireAdmin()
#1 .../craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\AppController->actionGetUpgradeModal()
#2 .../craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#3 .../craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#4 .../craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#5 .../craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('getUpgradeModal')
#6 .../craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(784): CWebApplication->runController('app/getUpgradeM...')
#7 .../craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(276): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#8 .../craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#9 .../craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#10 .../index.php(19): require_once('/storage/av0308...')
#11 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/app/getUpgradeModal
HTTP_REFERER=http://gtcarts.com/admin/dashboard
---
2015/09/21 22:30:32 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in .../craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (584)
2015/09/21 22:30:32 [error] [application] in .../craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (95)
```

Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: A 403 error generally indicates a permissions issue... Check to make sure that your entire `app`, `config`, and `storage` folders have the permissions they need to be written to.

Comment: @LindseyD Permissions are set properly. Just to be sure, I set them all to 777 and am still getting the error.

Comment: Do you have something like Suhosin or mod_security installed? Maybe one of their rules are blocking that request?

Comment: On second glance it looks like maybe you're on ArcusTech and they don't have those installed by default. If you can't get it sorted, hit us up at support@buildwithcraft.com with some CP/FTP creds and we can look into  it and update here with what we find.